# 80s or 90's science fiction book series

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space-exploration, space-colonization

I'm trying to remember the name of the author and/or books in a science fiction paperback book series I read years ago.  There were at least 2 ships that left earth, but due to a disagreement about their destination they separate and the story focuses mostly on one ship.  They land on and colonize a planet and eventually find a race of Egyptian like aliens also living on the planet.  They end up being attacked by another set of aliens that enslave other life-forms and use them as parts in their spacecraft.

Comment: Welcome to  Science Fiction & Fantasy  Stack Exchange. Can you estimate how long these books were?  E.g., were they flimsy mass-market paperbacks, or were they great novel(s) that just happened to be bound in paper? Do you remember anything about the cover(s)?  Male or female author?  Well known or unknown? What country and language did you read it in?

Comment: There are thousands of books to go through, so anything that narrows it down will be helpful.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it more complete.   See also [our guidance](//scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: This sounds like the America 2040 series by Evan Innes.